# A counterexample about an inequality- Field extensions

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Consider $A$ and $B$ two intermediate fields of the field extension F/K.

I have already proved that $[AB:K]\leq {[A:K][B:K]\over [A\cap B: K]}$.

I would like to find a simple example (for example, taking K= $\mathbb Q)$  in which it doesn't hold the equality (a counterexaple to show that the equality only happens sometimes) , but all the examples that come to my mand follow the equality.

Do you have any idea?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}$, $A = \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$ and $B = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta2^{1/3})$ (here $\zeta$ denotes a primitive cube root of one, so that $\zeta2^{1/3}$ is one of the other roots of the polynomial $x^3 - 2$).

The right hand side of your inequality is nine since these fields obviously intersect to $\mathbb{Q}$ (being unequal extensions of degree 3). The left hand side is six because the compositum of $A$ and $B$ is the splitting field of $x^3 - 2$, which splits in any field containing $2^{1/3}$ and $\zeta$, but the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is just $x^2 + x + 1$.

Comment: if you haven't encountered cube roots of unity before, it may be easier to picture the example where $A = \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})$ and $B = \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4}i)$.

Comment: In this case, $AB=\mathbb Q(2^{1/4},2^{1/4}i)$ and which would be$[AB:\mathbb Q]$???

Comment: @Triana in that case $[AB: \mathbb{Q}] = 8$ (since you can get it by adjoining $i$ to $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})$.)

Comment: And in the other side we have 16, because the intersection is $\mathbb Q$? Thank you @hunter

Comment: @Triana uh-oh, sorry. the example in the comments is no good -- the intersection is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and we get $8 = 8$. The example in the answer is still correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think useful motivation would be to consider an extension of $AB$ (call $L$) that is Galois over $A\cap B$. Then if $A= Fix(G_1)$ and $B= Fix(G_2)$, then $AB = Fix(G_1\cap G_2)$ and $A\cap B = Fix(G_1G_2)$ (where $G_1G_2$ is the minimal group that contains $G_1$ and $G_2$), so now you get an equivalent problem on groups, which is more intuitive.